# Access Query relationship doesn't return any results even though values are identical

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have two tables that I imported from Excel sheets, I created a query with a relationship that should show all rows where joined fields are equal.
The problem I'm facing is that the query isn't returning all values it should return, after investigating I found the below:
[image: Problem]
When I click on the cells as if I wanted to change the value, one of them keeps the decimals and the other one loses them.
This is the only difference, copy and pasting the first value solves the problem but the number of affected records is huge and it's not possible to change them one by one.
I don't know why this is happening they have the same formatting and properties in Excel and also in Access.
I thought I'd reach out to you and see if you know what's the issue?

Comment: What are the formats of the two cells? Make sure they both line up. One looks like it might be number or accounting and the other may be general.

Comment: Both of them are Accounting in Excel, and in Access both fields are Numbers with the same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem that occurs sometimes with imported data in Microsoft Access.

Since you state that re-typing or re-pasting the value fixes the problem, that indicates that the value wasn't precisely what you thought it was.

Microsoft Access may be displaying

> 16225  or  16225.00

But it is using a display format to do so.

The value that Microsoft Access has actually stored in the table field is actually something like

> 16225.00000000001

Which when displayed is being rounded to what you are seeing.  And, during a query join, obviously those two number are not exactly the same, hence the problem you are experiencing.

The problem generally comes from the source data that you imported.  Excel is storing the value in a format that Microsoft Access has to "convert" during the import.  Depending on how the value is stored in Excel, Access will incorrectly convert the number to something with a small fractional decimal.

One way you might "fix" this is to run an update query on the field with these values, updating them to themselves using the Round().

For example

```
UPDATE [MyTableName] SET [MyTableName].[MyFieldName] = Round([MyFieldName],0);
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it!  
I just changed the 0 at the end to 2 because i needed two decimals